# How to add a return function into a timer class in flash as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, for-loop, timer

Hi I've got a problem concerning a for loop. 
I have an array containing 3 MovieClips, I want to play each movieclip one by one, I'm planning on achieving this by using a timer class inside a for loop to delay the play(); of each MC.

Could anybody point me in the right direction, Shown below is my attempt of using a return function (unsuccessfully however)

```
//Shuffling the array to produce a random order when MC's are playing
function randomSort(a:*, b:*):Number
{
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) return -1;
    else return 1;
}
var obstacleArray:Array = [obstacleCar,obstacleCar2,obstacleCar3];
obstacleArray.sort(randomSort);


trace(obstacleArray);
trace(obstacleArray.length);

//OBSTACLE START DELAY
var timerPlay:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
timerPlay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, ontimerPlay);
timerPlay.start();
function ontimerPlay(evt:TimerEvent):void{

    //FOR EACH OBSTACLE

    var _i:Number=-1;
    for(var i:Number=0; i<obstacleArray.length; i++){

        var timerDelay:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
        timerDelay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, ontimerDelay);
        timerDelay.start();
        function ontimerDelay(evt:TimerEvent):void{

            _i = i;
            trace(obstacleArray[i]);
            obstacleArray[i].play();
            trace(i);
        }
    }
    return _i;
}
```

A big thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest doing this:

```
// ...

timerPlay.start();

// Move these two variables outside of ontimerPlay. Variables defined in functions 
// generally last only while the function is being executed.
var i:int = 0;
// The timer will fire three times. Each time it fires, i will be incremented.
var timerDelay:Timer = new Timer(1000, 3);

function ontimerPlay(evt:TimerEvent):void{
    // Remove the for loop. The way you had it, three timers were starting and ending 
    // all at the same time.

    timerDelay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, ontimerDelay);
    timerDelay.start();
}

function ontimerDelay(evt:TimerEvent):void{
    obstacleArray[i].play();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: how would you add a hittest into this code 
if (carTarget.hitTestObject(obstacleArray[i]) == true){
 trace("HIT!");
 }

as where ever this code is placed - it doesn't seem to function properly. Thanks again!

Comment: I think it would be best if you made your comment into a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if your function is going to return something, the type must not be "void".  Ergo...

```
function getNumber():Number {
    return 123;
}
```

Secondly, you'll want to start the timer, not spawn a function that creates a timer.  Also, I imagine you'll want to keep track of the length of each MovieClip.  Assuming they're potentially all different, the easiest way to do that would be in the same array you stored your MovieClips.

Try this instead (see the comments).

```
//Shuffling the array to produce a random order when MC's are playing
function randomSort(a:*, b:*):Number {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) return -1;
    else return 1;
}

// Array holds both the MovieClip reference as well as the duration of the clip.
var obstacleArray:Array = [
    {   "obj":obstacleCar,
        "duration":1050 },
    {   "obj":obstacleCar2,
        "duration":2500 },
    {   "obj":obstacleCar3,
        "duration":3857 }
];

obstacleArray.sort(randomSort);

// Holds the current index we're watching in the array
var currentIndex:int = 0;

// Create the timer and start it up.
var timerPlay:Timer = new Timer(10, 1);
timerPlay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, ontimerPlay);
timerPlay.start();

function ontimerPlay(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    obstacleArray[currentIndex].obj.play();

    // Increment the index.
    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;

    // If the index does not exceed the array length, start a timer for it.
    if (currentIndex < obstacleArray.length) {
        // And use the length specified in the array.
        timerPlay = new Timer(obstacleArray[currentIndex].duration, 1);
        timerPlay.start();
    }
}
```